# What is the purpose of cheap MBTs?

Tags: wargame-ee

How to use cheap low-end MBTs like Leopard-1A1? I don't understand how to use them.
For example, 2-3 M60s are nothing versus M1, they are simply cannon fodder. Soviet improved T-55s and T-62s at least have long-ranged ATGMs but NATO Leopards and Pattons really quite a weak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wargame-EE is all about positioning. A low-tech tank can easily destroy a high-tech tank when it manages to get it from the side or even from behind.

A single T-80 might beat 3 M60A1 Pattons when facing them head-on, but when the pattons split up, circle it and attack it from two sides simultaneously, the pattons will win the fight.

One could argue that the expensive tanks are even better for flanking, because they are generally faster and have stabilizers which make them more effective when on the move. But you have to keep in mind that flanking maneuvers are usually a very dangerous tactical move, because the flanker often risks to be flanked itself by other enemy tanks. The backs of the high-tech tanks are often only marginally less vulnerable than those of the low-tech ones (The most expensive tank in the game, the 180 points T-80U, has a back which is just as soft as that of the 45 points T-72), so by attempting to flank with an expensive tank, you are risking a lot more points for only a slightly larger reward.